# How to pass a value from a view to another view to populate another form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i pass a value from a view to another view to populate another form in rails 3?

I am new to rails and im a bit confused about how to achieve this, here is my scenerio:

I generated a Clients and a Sales scaffold, then in the Clients index view i placed a search text field which searchs for the clients and renders them below it. Each client has a button called Sale, when clicked it should redirect you to the new_sales_path and automatically fill some fields of the form with the values of the client, like for example: name, address, id, phone number, etc...

So what i want to do is:
I want to pass the information of the client when the button Sale is clicked and then polute the new_sales form.

So i have this code in index clients view:

```
<%= form_tag clientes_path, :method => 'get', :id => "clientes_search", :class => "form-search" do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "input-medium search-query" %>

<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "btn" %>

<% @clients.each do |client| %>
<tr>
<td><%= client.id %></td>
<td><%= client.email %></td>
...
...
<%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                  edit_client_path(client), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
<%= link_to "Sale", new_sale_path, :action => 'sale_button', :id => 'sale_button', :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
<% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

In my application helper i have:

```
def sale_button
@sale_button = client
end
```

In my clients and sales controllers i have the line:

```
helper_method :sale_button
```

And in my new sales view i have

```
<div id='sales'>
<%= simple_form_for @sale, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %> 
<%= f.input :client, :label => "Client ID", :required => true, :as => :string, :input_html => { :value => @sale_button.id } %>
...
... 
<% end %>
```

I dont know if i am doing it the right way or if there is something that im missing, any help or input is welcome.

Im using Rails 3.2 btw

---

Sales controller

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
helper_method :boton_venta


  # GET /sales
  # GET /sales.json
  def index
    @sales = Sale.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    @lista_porcentajes = Porcentaje.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sales }
      format.js
    end
  end

  # GET /sales/1
  # GET /sales/1.json
  def show
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sale }
    end
  end

  # GET /sales/new
  # GET /sales/new.json
  def new
    @sale = Sale.new
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sale }
      format.json { render json: @client }
    end
  end

  # GET /sales/1/edit
  def edit
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /sales
  # POST /sales.json
  def create
    @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @sale, status: :created, location: @sale }
      else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /sales/1
  # PUT /sales/1.json
  def update
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.update_attributes(params[:sale])
        format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sales/1
  # DELETE /sales/1.json
  def destroy
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
    @sale.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sales_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def sort_column
    Sale.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "id"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Puntodeventa::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :empresas

  resources :cliente_grupo_empresas

  devise_for :users, :admin_empresas, :empresa_users, :cliente_users, :admins

  resources :relacion_porcentaje_grupoempresas

  resources :relacion_grupo_empresas

  resources :porcentajes

  resources :categoria_empresas

  resources :grupo_empresas

  resources :sales

  resources :cliente_empresas

  resources :clients

  get "home/index"

  resources :productos

  root :to => "home#index"
```

rake routes

```
sales GET    /sales(.:format)                                      sales#index
                                  POST   /sales(.:format)                                      sales#create
                         new_sale GET    /sales/new(.:format)                                  sales#new
                        edit_sale GET    /sales/:id/edit(.:format)                             sales#edit
                             sale GET    /sales/:id(.:format)                                  sales#show
                                  PUT    /sales/:id(.:format)                                  sales#update
                                  DELETE /sales/:id(.:format)                                  sales#destroy
```

sales new.html.erb

```
<%- model_class = @sale.class -%>
<h1><%=t '.title', :default => t('helpers.titles.new', :model =>     model_class.model_name.human,
                               :default => "New #{model_class.model_name.human}") %>      </h1>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

Form being rendered in sales new.html.erb

```
    <div id='sales'>

<%= simple_form_for @sale, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :client, :label => "Serial del cliente", :required => true, :as => :text, :input_html => { :value => ' ' } %>
  <%= f.association :client, :label_method => :nombre, :label_value => :id, :required => true, :as => :string %>
  <%= f.association :porcentaje, :label_method => :porcentaje, :value_method => :porcentaje, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :monto_venta, :required => true, :as => :string %>
  <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
  <%= f.association :empresa, :label_method => :nombre, :value_method => :id, :required => true %>
  <% else %>
  <% f.association :empresa, :disabled => true, :input_html => { :value => current_user.empresa_id } %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                sales_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

New sales view with the modification you suggested.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "id", "Id" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "name", "Name" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "grupo_empresa", "Grupo" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "telefono", "Telefono" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "celular", "Celular" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "email", "Email" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "serial_cliente", "Serial del cliente" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "puntos_cliente", "Puntos del cliente" %></th>
        <th><%= sortable "created_at", "Creado el" %></th>
        <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to client.nombre, client_path(client) %></td>
        <td><%= client.grupo_empresa.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= client.telefono %></td>
        <td><%= client.celular %></td>
        <td><%= client.email %></td>
        <td><%= client.serial_client %></td>
          <td><%=l client.created_at %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_client_path(client), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
        <%= link_to "Sale", new_sale_path, :client_id => client.id , :id => 'boton_venta', :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen carefully,

The following link "Sale" should be somewhere in your application.

```
<%= link_to "Sale", new_sale_path, :client_id => client.id , :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

If an User clicks that link, link_to method checks for the path and you have mentioned it as "new_sale_path"

From your **"rake routes",**

```
new_sale GET    /sales/new(.:format)                                  sales#new
```

It is clear that new_sale_path is referring to sales#new( sales controller, new action)

If you add underscore path, rails will take care of that. For example, edit_sale_path will execute sales controller, edit action/method.

After this step, since the new action in sales controller is executed, rails will look for a "new.html.erb" file in app/views/sales.

If it exists, that html.erb file will be displayed/rendered in your browser.

You should understand the above working.

Now, lets get specific.

When that sale link is clicked, the application reaches the sales#new action with :client_id as a parameter in the params hash.

You can access that params hash as follows,

```
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
```

You have done that. The above statement, takes the passed :client_id as input and finds the right client from the database using the Client model and find method.

Now the instance variable is set with a record from Clients table matching the :client_id.

Instance variable is @client.

Now, In your view you can use the instance variable @client as follows, which you have not done, or Im not seeing. What is there in app/views/sales/_form.html.erb ?

Please post that too.

```
<%- model_class = @sale.class -%>
<h1><%=t '.title', :default => t('helpers.titles.new', :model =>     model_class.model_name.human,
                               :default => "New #{model_class.model_name.human}") %>      </h1>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

If you use a form_for like below,

```
<% form_for @client do |client| %>

<% text_field_tag client.name %>
-
-
-

<% end %>
```

There will be a text_field which will be pre populated with the client's name.

If you dont understand anything, tell me.

If you understood few things and couldn't figure out few things, tell me.

If you understood everything, tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: oh ok, yes i understand what you are saying, but maybe i did not explain myself properly, let me try. I have 2 tables, clients and sales, the sale button i mentioned is in the clients index view "app/views/clients/index.html.erb" and it shows all the clients, and each client has a sale button. When this button is pressed it redirects the user to the new sales view "app/views/sales/new.html.erb" and this works good, it does redirects me to it and shows the page. What i cannot do is pass the id of the specific client to the new sales view, i dont know how to do it because...

Comment: they are in different controllers, "app/controllers/clients_controller.erb" and "app/controllers/sales_controller.erb".
I will paste the clients index view where the sale button appear so you know what im talking about.

Comment: Listen, try this, you are passing the client id as a parameter in this link. <%= link_to "Sale",{ :controller => "sales", :action => "new", :client_id => client.id} , {:class => 'btn btn-mini'} %>. Now use this as your Sale link. Click on it and copy and paste the URL you are getting on your browsers address bar, after clicking on it.

Comment: Actually in my question the first piece of code is my clients index view so there you can see the sale button which redirects to the sales new path.

Comment: Ok replace that link with, <%= link_to "Sale",{ :controller => "sales", :action => "new", :client_id => client.id} , {:class => 'btn btn-mini'} %>. Now use this as your Sale link. Click on it and copy and paste the URL you are getting on your browsers address bar, after clicking on it.

Comment: ok ill try that, thank you for your patience man, first time i post here

Comment: Wow! it worked! :D i have not populated the form yet with the info of the client but i got no errors when clicking the sale button, it redirected me to the new sales view and also it says the client_id number in the url of the page, something like "/sales/new?client_id=12" so i guess it should work now, ill try to populate the form now

Comment: Thats right, Now.. this code in sales#new action..@client = Client.find(params[:client_id]), should fetch you the Client details with client_id 12. You can check this by doing a "rails console" and in your console prompt, type this.."@client = Client.find(12)". That should return a active record and store it in @client. If you have found the answer, be kind enough to mark it as the right answer so that it will help other people.

Comment: Yes it worked like a charm :) and to fetch the info of the client in the new sale view all i had to do was `code`<%= f.association :cliente, :label => "Name", :input_html => { :value => @cliente.name } %> `code` this to get the name of the client for example, thank you for your time beck03076

Comment: I think there are other inefficient things done in your app, I can help you with that too. Anyway if you have anyother questions, post it in stackoverflow, you will get the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes i did i think, i click in the arrow next to the answer and it became green. Thats how you do it right? :O

Comment: Ah, what things do you think are innefficient in it? i would be glad to know if they could be done in a better way

Comment: Thats a whole new discussion. or sometime called a new project.

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the client_id as params to this link as,**

```
 <%= link_to "Sale", new_sale_path, :client_id => client.id , :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

Make sure new_sale_path hits the sales controller, new action.

In the new action access the client_id as params[:client_id] and fetch the current client record and render a form with that as follows,

```
SalesController

def new
 @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
 -
 -
 -
 render 'new'
end
```

In your view, new.html.erb, you have to write a form_for @client as,

```
<% form_for @client do |client| %>

<% text_field_tag client.name %>
-
-
-

<% end %>
```

Now, Im not sure about my syntax. Try to understand what Im doing here.

Thanks.

Comment: I did what you suggested and when it is redirecting me to the new_sales_path i get the following error:

Couldn't find Client without an ID

Comment: Thats the error, and also it says:
app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:34:in `new'

Comment: So i think whats happenning is that the variable client_id is nil so  thats why the "new" action in sales controller is complainning. If you need the full trace, is here: http://pastebin.com/48sLafTJ

Comment: Copy paste your app/controllers/sales_controller.rb and app/views/sales/new.html.erb code and also your routes.rb, please!